# Extend Antlr grammar file with lists

Tags: grammar, antlr4

I have the following assignment about extending an Antlr grammar.

[image]

What I've tried is:

[image]

I am not sure whether this is the correct solution or not. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 problems here: 1) you have 2 the same alt-labels (`# Lists`), and 2) you only allow zero or a single expression in your list. It should be this:

```
expr
 : ...
 | '(' expr ')'                    # Parenthesis
 | '[' ( expr ( ',' expr )* )? ']' # Lists
 ;
```

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense.